# Portrait Orientation for android apps when running on Android Sticks/ Amazon Stick

Tags: android, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, amazon-fire-tv

I am working on an application which I want to run both on android tablets and android-sticks.

I want the application to run in the portrait mode. I can easily achieve this in a tablet but when I run the same application on an android-stick it doesn't work. The android-stick display (I connected the stick to a normal tv through HDMI) always appears in the landscape mode. It seems like the android stick simply ignores the orientation change code I have written (inside onCreate()) :-

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

What I want is that the app's orientation should change from Landscape to Portrait when running on an android-stick (or amazon-stick).

Can you please help me here ?

Comment: why do you want to display a portrait application on a TV? I think from when I looked at this a while ago Android TV devices only support Landscape

Comment: If you really want your app in portrait mode, remove android tv from your supported devices. But like what @Offbeatmammal said, I can't see why you would want portrait for tv

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android TV box then all you have to do is 
Download the screen orientation application and put it in portrait mode.
Then go to the setting of android TV box and then to display and put the screen orientation to default.
This will change your TV screen orientation to portrait and if you want to put in back in landscape just go to the app and click landscape and press ohk

My android TV box was rooted not sure this will work on non rooted devices or not